# How to horizontal alignment radion button in Django model form with adminlte boostrap theme?

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates

**here my model.py**

```
class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
    select = (
        ('Yes','Yes'),
        ('No','No'),
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    r = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=b_sele, default='R')
```

**here my form.py**

```
class MedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalRecord
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['status','create_by','create_at','update_at']

        widgets = {
            'code':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Code', 'readonly':'readonly'}),
            'patient_id':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),

            'r':forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'}),
```

**here my template**

```
<form>
 <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                {{form.r}}
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{form.auto_id}}">Option 1</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
</form>
```

**I am trying to align horizontal radion button but I can't guide me how to align radio button **